# jQuery not working after moving WordPress site to new domain

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I just moved my site to a new domain on hostgator and now the site's content is not showing. The site that dosen't work is http://alcaldarone.com and the site that I developed with and works is http://atcjr.alcaldarone.com.

If I look at the problem site in Chrome and refresh the Home page, I can see the content flash for a split second then it disappears. I think the problem is that jQuery is not loading. The Blog page content appears but the jQuery slide function isn't executing either.

I have gone through the database and changed the URL settings for home and siteurl in wp-options to point to alcaldarone.com and did the same for records in the wp-posts table, but still no luck...any ideas?

Comment: The links on http:/alcaldarone.com still points to http://atcjr.alcaldarone.com (e.g. the home and services links)

Comment: Apologies...the icons still pointed to atcjr.alcaldarone.com but the text links were correct...I just corrected the icon links but still same problem

Comment: I got this error with FireBug : `f.easing[i.animatedProperties[this.prop]] is not a function`

Comment: I'll look into that but it works on atcjr.caldarone.com...wondering what I could be missing...all the files seem to be there...

Comment: Seems that jquery is simply not being loaded for some reason...would there be some other file I need to bring over or plugin to load?...I'm calling wp_enqueue_script in the header... –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found this. For some reason my jquery-ui.min.js was not getting loaded. I just called

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js">
```

instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

and that did it. The script probably got corrupted when moving the files..